# I can't extract NSDictionary values using swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I'm having hard time extracting the values from an NSDictionary object after I had parsed it from a json data-object. ![enter image description here][1]

```
var stationsInfo: NSArray = stationsDictionary["stations"]! as NSArray
            for aStation in stationsInfo{
                //parse the information
                var station = aStation as NSDictionary
                println("next")
                var example: NSDictionary = ["key": "val", "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3"]
                var ex: String = example["key2"] as String
                println(station)
                var age_in_days : Double         = station["age_in_days"] as Double
                var hight_normal: Double         = station["height_nom"]  as Double
                var hight_over  : Double         = station["height_ovr"]  as Double
                var latitude: CLLocationDegrees  = station["lat"]         as Double
                var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = station["lon"]         as Double
                var station_id  : Int            = station["station_id"]  as Int
```

The var ex ends up equal to "val2" as it is suppose to work, but I keep getting strange errors when I try to get the values stored in the station dictionary.

This happens despite that the value of station is as follows

> {
>       "age_in_days" = 1401753600;
>       "height_nom" = "13.5";
>       "height_ovr" = "14.0";
>       lat = "24.084082";
>       lon = "89.023476";
>       "station_id" = 1;
>   }

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting it as a Swift dictionary. Do you know what the key and value are? If so, replace the AnyObjects with those types. You can try AnyObject anyways, but you might have to do other casting because of that.

```
var station = aStation as [AnyObject:AnyObject]
```

Comment: Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Comment: When I used [String: AnyObject], It crashed as well.

Comment: Thanks @Nick your answer helped redirect my questioning. I found the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong!

Apparently All the JSON values are of type string by default.

> {
>       "age_in_days" = 1401753600;
>       "height_nom" = "13.5";
>       "height_ovr" = "14.0";
>       lat = "24.084082";
>       lon = "89.023476";
>       "station_id" = 1;
>   }

So the correct way of fetching out a double value is:

```
var dataDictionary  = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataInput, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

var stationsInfo: NSArray = stationsDictionary["stations"]! as NSArray
for station in stationsInfo{
//parse the information
var age_in_days : Int            = (station["age_in_days"] as     String).toInt()!
var hight_normal: Double         = (station["height_nom"] as     NSString).doubleValue
var hight_over  : Double         = (station["height_ovr"] as     NSString).doubleValue
var latitude: CLLocationDegrees  = (station["lat"]        as     NSString).doubleValue
var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = (station["lon"]        as     NSString).doubleValue
var station_id  : Int            = (station["station_id"] as     String).toInt()!
```

Note: type String doesn't include a .toDouble( ) function, which is why I had to use type NSString instead.

ALSO, VERY IMPORTANT NOTE: the two keys "age_in_days" and "station_id" appear as of type int in JSON (as in the quote above), but the NSJSONSerialization function fetches all the values as of type String!